# Can I assign an element location found in page_source with .any? method to a variable so I can reference it later in Ruby code?

Tags: css, ruby, selenium-webdriver

I scan page_source with

```
CONSTANTS = [' AA1 ',  ' AA2 ', ' AB3 ', ' AB4 ', " AC5 ", ' AC6 ',' AN11 ',' BN12 ']

if CONSTANTS.any? {|pc| @a = pc if driver.page_source.include?(pc)}
```

I need to be able to access the element found, so I can click the button next to it. The actual element location is dynamic, changes every few seconds and looks like this.

```
css=.ng-scope:nth-child(3) > .ng-scope:nth-child(3).btn
```

There is no id or name. Page source is able to verify that item has been found but there is nothing else I can do with it.

Is there anything I have been missing here? Thanks

Comment: `driver.find_element(:css, '.ng-scope:nth-child(3) > .ng-scope:nth-child(3).btn')` should work

Comment: thanks Stefan, but there is still an element missing. How can I assign this very element to a variable. I have found something from page_source, but have no idea how to assign it

Comment: _"I have found something"_ is quite vague. Can you be more specific or maybe post an example, please?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `CONSTANTS` is an `Enumerable`, the method to find a matching element is not `any?`, but `find`. From the Ruby-Docs for `find`:

*Returns the first for which block is not false.*

Comment: no I should've added that. CONSTANTS are array of strings.
On this website I have 2 levels of problem. 
1) Verify that ANY of CONSTs is available ( that I have already done )
2) gain access to the CONST so I can perform some action on it. Here I failed miserably

Comment: @ArturMrozinski _"I should've added that"_ you can still [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64661225/edit) your question.

Comment: Great. So, in what way does my answer not cover your problem?

Comment: User, I am not sure frankly. I can see how I can find an item in the source code, but my program refuses to assign the finding to a variable and I am completely unable to do anything with it. All I am able to do atm is to verify the finding is on the page, but nothing else

Comment: In this case, you should ask a new question with the modified code, so that we can discuss the new problem. Assigning the result of an expression to a variable should be something we likely can sort out easily.